# How do I lock a Google Sheet during a specific time period everyday?

Tags: google-sheets

My google spreadsheet should only be editable between 12 AM to 8 AM everyday.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: @pnuts 8 hours. 12 AM = 00:00 and 8 AM = 08:00.

Answer (score 1):

With a script, one can add sheet protection using [protect](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#protect()) method, and remove it using [remove](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/protection#remove()) method. Using [time-driven triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers), set the following functions to run daily, `protectAll` should run at 8am and `unprotectAll` at 12am.

Both functions loop over all sheets in the active spreadsheet, protecting or unprotecting them.

```
function protectAll() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    sheets[i].protect().setDescription("Temporary protection");
  }
}

function unprotectAll() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    var protection = sheet.getProtections(SpreadsheetApp.ProtectionType.SHEET)[0];
    if (protection) {
      protection.remove();
    }
  }
}
```